# Extracting Key-Phrases from text based on the Topic with Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have a large dataset with 3 columns, columns are text, phrase and topic. 
I want to find a way to extract key-phrases (phrases column) based on the topic.
Key-Phrase can be part of the text value or the whole text value.

```
import pandas as pd


text = ["great game with a lot of amazing goals from both teams",
        "goalkeepers from both teams made misteke",
        "he won all four grand slam championchips",
        "the best player from three-point line",
        "Novak Djokovic is the best player of all time",
        "amazing slam dunks from the best players",
        "he deserved yellow-card for this foul",
        "free throw points"]

phrase = ["goals", "goalkeepers", "grand slam championchips", "three-point line", "Novak Djokovic", "slam dunks", "yellow-card", "free throw points"]

topic = ["football", "football", "tennis", "basketball", "tennis", "basketball", "football", "basketball"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"text":text,
                   "phrase":phrase,
                   "topic":topic})

print(df.text)
print(df.phrase)
```

I'm having big trouble with finding a path to do something like this, because I have more than 50000 rows in my dataset and around 48000 of unique values of phrases, and 3 different topics.

I guess that building a dataset with all football, basketball and tennis topics are not really the best solution. So I was thinking about making some kind of ML model for this, but again that  means that I will have 2 features (text and topic) and one result (phrase), but I will have more than 48000 of different classes in my result, and that is not a good approach.

I was thinking about using text column as a feature and applying classification model in order to find sentiment. After that I can use predicted sentiment to extract key features, but I do not know how to extract them.

One more problem is that I get only 66% accuracy when I try to classify sentiment by using `CountVectorizer` or `TfidfTransformer` with Random Forest, Decision Tree, or any other classifying algorithm, and also 66% of accuracy if Im using `TextBlob` for sentiment analysis.

Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like a good approach here would be to use a [Latent Dirichlet allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) model, which is an example of what are known as [topic models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model).

---

A `LDA` is a an unsupervised model that finds similar groups among a set of observations, which you can then use to assign a *topic* to each of them. Here I'll go through what could be an approach to solve this by training a model using the sentences in the `text` column. Though in the case the `phrases` are representative enough an contain the necessary information to be captured by the models, then they could also be a good (possibly better) candidate for training the model, though that you'll better judge by yourself.

Before you train the model, you need to apply some preprocessing steps, including tokenizing the sentences, removing stopwords, lemmatizing and stemming. For that you can use `nltk`:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import lda
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

ignore = set(stopwords.words('english'))
stemmer = WordNetLemmatizer()
text = []
for sentence in df.text:
    words = word_tokenize(sentence)
    stemmed = []
    for word in words:
        if word not in ignore:
            stemmed.append(stemmer.lemmatize(word))
    text.append(' '.join(stemmed))
```

Now we have more appropriate corpus to train the model:

```
print(text)

['great game lot amazing goal team',
 'goalkeeper team made misteke',
 'four grand slam championchips',
 'best player three-point line',
 'Novak Djokovic best player time',
 'amazing slam dunk best player',
 'deserved yellow-card foul',
 'free throw point']
```

We can then convert the text to a matrix of token counts through [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), which is the input `LDA` will be expecting:

```
vec = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1))
X = vec.fit_transform(text)
```

Note that you can use the `ngram` parameter to spacify the n-gram range you want to consider to train the model. By setting `ngram_range=(1,2)` for instance you'd end up with features containing all individual words as well as `2-grams` in each sentence, here's an example having trained `CountVectorizer` with `ngram_range=(1,2)`:

```
vec.get_feature_names()
['amazing',
 'amazing goal',
 'amazing slam',
 'best',
 'best player',
 ....
```

The advantage of using `n-grams` is that you could then also find `Key-Phrases` other than just single words.

Then we can train the `LDA` with whatever amount of topics you want, in this case I'll just be selecting `3` topics (note that this has nothing to do with the `topics` column), which you can consider to be the `Key-Phrases` - or `words` in this case - that you mention. Here I'll be using [`lda`](https://lda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), though there are several options such as [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html).
Each topic will have associated a set of words from the vocabulary it has been trained with, with each word having a *score* measuring the relevance of the word in a topic.

```
model = lda.LDA(n_topics=3, random_state=1)
model.fit(X)
```

Through `topic_word_` we can now obtain these *scores* associated to each topic. We can use `argsort` to sort the vector of scores, and use it to index the vector of feature names, which we can obtain with `vec.get_feature_names`:

```
topic_word = model.topic_word_

vocab = vec.get_feature_names()
n_top_words = 3

for i, topic_dist in enumerate(topic_word):
    topic_words = np.array(vocab)[np.argsort(topic_dist)][:-(n_top_words+1):-1]
    print('Topic {}: {}'.format(i, ' '.join(topic_words)))

Topic 0: best player point
Topic 1: amazing team slam
Topic 2: yellow novak card
```

---

The printed results don't really represent much in this case, since the model has been trained with the sample from the question, however you should see more clear and meaningful *topics* by training with your entire corpus.

Also note that for this example I've use the whole vocabulary to train the model. However it seems that in your case what would make more sense, is to split the text column into groups according to the different `topics` you already have, and **train a separate model on each group**. But hopefully this gives you a good idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have 3 questions. First, is it possible to evaluate this model with some kind of accuracy or score?
Second, I saw 'likelyhood' parameter when I run the code, and the value is around -1700, what does that mean? And third,  what do you mean by "train a separate model on each group", what would I get with that?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're looking to group short pieces of text by topic. You will have to tokenize the data in one way or another. There are a variety of encodings that you could consider:

Bag of words, which classifies by counting the frequency of each word in your vocabulary.

TF-IDF: Does what's above but makes words that appear in more entries less important

n_grams / bigrams / trigrams which essentially does the bag of words method but also maintains some context around each word. So you'll have encodings for each word but you'll also have tokens for "great_game", "game_with" and "great_game_with" etc.

Orthogonal Sparse Bigrams (OSB)s Also create features that have the words further apart, like "great__with"

Any of these options could be ideal for your dataset (the last two are likely your best bet). If none of these options work, There are a few more options you could try:

---

First you could use word embeddings. These are vector representations of each word that unlike one-hot-encoding intrinsically contain word meaning. You can sum the words in a sentence together to get a new vector containing the general idea of what the sentence is about which can then be decoded.

You can also use word embeddings alongside a Bidirectional LSTM. This is the most computationally intensive option but if your other options are not working this might be a good choice. biLSTMs try to interpret sentences by looking at the context around words to try to understand what the word might mean in that context.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think what your looking for is called "Topic modeling" in NLP.
you should try using LDA for topic modeling. It's one of easiest methods to apply.
also as @Mike mentioned, converting word to vector has many approaches. You should first try simple approaches like count vectorizer and then gradually move to something like word-2-vect or glove.

I am attaching some links for applying LDA to the corpus. 
1. https://towardsdatascience.com/nlp-extracting-the-main-topics-from-your-dataset-using-lda-in-minutes-21486f5aa925
2. https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-visualization-how-to-present-results-lda-models/